# Top part of Fragment get's hidden under the Toolbar which has elevation. How do I bring the fragment to full screen [Overlapping Toolbar]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am having **RelativeLayout as root layout**, and it's id is container. Toolbar has an elevation of 4dp. When I am adding a Fragment in R.id.container [RelativeLayout], the Fragment is launching with part of it under the Toolbar.

**However when I remove the elevation on Toolbar, Fragment is appearing above the Toolbar.** which is what I want. But I want to keep the elevation, and I don't want to change the elevation to 0, while inflating the Fragment, because I am using animations.

***How do I get the Fragment on top of Toolbar.***

This is the XML code

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_4dp"
        android:text="Chiri"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in Activity

```
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new UploadFragment()).commit();
```

This is how my UI looks right now

[image]

Comment: If you want to have toolbar at bottom maybe set layout_alignbottomParent to true. Also please put two screens with non-expected and desired view

Comment: Sorry dude, what I meant by bottom is I want the Fragment to overlap the toolbar. Right now, since Toolbar has elevation, it appears above the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

But the frameLayout or the fragment tag under the toolbar, also make sure the root tag is linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

I know this is somewhat old now, but showing up for me on Google searches, and no answer, so to help anyone else who stumbles here...

I had this problem too. The answer for me was to define a sibling layout to the layout.

Currently R.id.container is the root in this layout. Create a new parent, and a sibling layout to R.id.container (say R.id.fragment_container), and use that to replace the fragment.

```
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new UploadFragment()).commit();
```